# swig c++ to perl : how to use c++11 string STL functions

Tags: c++, perl, c++11, stl, swig

I would like to call c++ functions from a website that uses Perl.
The c++ code works fine, I am getting troubles from SWIG wrapper regarding some new function from c++11 in < string> STL. in this case stoi(string), while the problem is the same with other functions like string.pop_back(), stol... all functions brought to < string> with c++11 vesrsion.

how to make SWIG take into account those new functions so that it can compile ?

Here is the error message I got
*error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’*

```
/* --- source fonctions.cpp --- */
bool checkRIB(std::string word){
    cout << "verification du rib : "<< word<<endl;
    if (word.size()!=23) return false;
    for (size_t i=0; i!=word.size(); i++) {
        if (!isdigit(word[i])){
            if ((word[i]>='A'&&word[i]<='I')){
                word[i]= (int)(word[i]-'A')%10+'1';
            }else if ((word[i]>='J'&&word[i]<='R')){
                word[i]= (int)(word[i]-'J')%10+'1';
            } else if ((word[i]>='S'&&word[i]<='Z')){
                word[i]= (int)(word[i]-'S')%10+'2';
            } else cout << "mauvais code"<<endl;
        }
    }   
    return ( (97-((89*std::stoi(word.substr(0,5)) + 15*std::stoi(word.substr(5,5))+3*std::stol(word.substr(10,11))) % 97)) == std::stoi(word.substr(21,2)) );
}

/* --- header fonctions.h--- */
#ifndef DEF_FONCTIONS
#define DEF_FONCTIONS

#include <fstream>      // pour lecture / ecriture de fichiers
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
bool checkRIB(std::string word);
#endif

/* --- interface code interface.i --- */
%module interface
%include"std_string.i"
%include "std_map.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%{ 
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
    bool checkRIB(std::string word);
}
bool seRessemblent(const std::string &s1, const std::string & s2, float seuil=0.65);

%}
bool checkRIB(std::string word);
```

and the foolowing steps for the compilation (on Ubuntu) :

```
1% swig -c++ -perl5 interface.i
2% g++ -c `perl -MConfig -e 'print join(" ", @Config{qw(ccflags optimize cccdlflags)}, "-I$Config{archlib}/CORE")'` fonctions.cpp interface_wrap.cxx
(here error : *error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’*)
3% g++ `perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{lddlflags}'` fonctions.o interface_wrap.o -o interface.so
```

The interface is working fine on other functions (Not displayed for space reason)

Thank you for helping

Alexis

Comment: You need to pass `-std=c++11` to gcc. swig must have a way of passing additional compiler flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to work around the problem: 
I split the compilation procedure from

```
1% swig -c++ -perl5 interface.i
2% g++ -c `perl -MConfig -e 'print join(" ", @Config{qw(ccflags optimize cccdlflags)}, "-I$Config{archlib}/CORE")'` fonctions.cpp interface_wrap.cxx
(here error : *error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’*)
3% g++ `perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{lddlflags}'` fonctions.o interface_wrap.o -o interface.so
```

to

```
1% swig -c++ -perl5 interface.i
2% g++ -c -fPIC fonctions.cpp -std=c++11
3% g++ -c `perl -MConfig -e 'print join(" ", @Config{qw(ccflags optimize cccdlflags)}, "-I$Config{archlib}/CORE")'` interface_wrap.cxx
4% g++ `perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{lddlflags}'` fonctions.o interface_wrap.o -o interface.so
```

This way the ordinary c++ code is compiled in c++11 as needed.
the -fPIC option is to be used so that the libraries can be joined.

I could not find a way to use c++11with the interface wrapper though.